# react native google signin return status code: 12501

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-play-services, google-signin

I need to have google sign in my react native app. So i google it a lot an i find [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) that seems awesome, but im stuck with one error.

I follow all the steps in the [READ.me](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) and [Androide Guide](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md)

i have the following code:

```
 componentDidMount() {


     GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({autoResolve: true}).then(() => {
        // play services are available. can now configure library
        GoogleSignin.configure({
            scopes: [
                'email', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
            ],
            webClientId: 'web-clientid from the console developper',
            offlineAccess: true
        }).then(() => {
            // you can now call currentUserAsync()
            GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync().then((user) => {
                console.log('USER', user);
            }).done();
        });
     });
}

signIn() {
    GoogleSignin.signIn()
        .then((user) => {
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
        })
        .done();
}

 render() {
    return (
        <Image source={BACKGROUND} style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={ICON}></Image>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                APP TEST
            </Text>

            <GoogleSigninButton
                style={{width: 230, height: 48}}
                size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Standard}
                color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
                onPress={this.signIn}
            />
        </Image>
    );
```

When i click in the sign in button, pops up a window for i choose which  google account i want to use. but when i choose the account, i have the follow error : WRONG SIGNIN Error: unknown status code: 12501(…)

So i look in the faqs that hare in the bottom of [Androide Guide](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md) 
and confirm that my certificate_hash in  `android/app/google-services.json` are the same.
I also check that the aplication id in my `app/build.graddle` are the same that i enter in the google cloud.

I think that the problem are with the WebclientId that i pass in my scope, i'm passin the web type one, but already try the two clients id that are in  the oauth 2

[image: screen]

I search in githubs issues and i find someone told to download the google-services again. i do that, but the file is equal to the file i previous download.
pretty sure, i'm  missing something, but dont no what.
Can anyone helping me?

I open an issue in the github, but i dont get much action.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The readme you shared states

> D. After the sign-in completes I get the following error error code
>   12501. what to do ?
>
> This is a permission error. Make sure the certificate_hash in
>   android/app/google-services.json matches your certificate.
>
> To get your sha1-hash
>
> keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v Also
>   make sure the application id matches the one you enter on the cloud
>   console.

There is a .user file(or something like that)which I can't remember off the top of my head. It is in a hidden folder so you will have to use the finder to look for that file and delete it. It should work then. Look at all of the paths that your code uses to find it, you will have to debug those files for the path.

Comment: thanks for help.
however i dont  understand very well what you said. How can i find a hidden file, when i dont know the name?

Comment: You are going to have to debug the code for file paths and check them out.

Comment: He mean that FAQ - https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md#d-after-the-sign-in-completes-i-get-the-following-error-error-code-12501-what-to-do-

Answer (score 0):

Might this will help you, try this:

- Check your google-services.json cirtificate_hash code.
   match it with your Android Signing Certificate SHA-1.
   use this link to reach their https://developers.google.com/mobile
- I have tested it on emulator but emulator don't have google play services so I tested it on my android mobile phone.
- Use the fallowing code

  ```
  import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';
  ```

then

```
componentDidMount() {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
        scopes: [
            'email', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
        ],
        webClientId: 'use here oauth_client[{client_id}]',//refer this given below example:
        offlineAccess: true
    }).then(() => {
        // you can now call currentUserAsync()
        GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync().then((user) => {
             //user = GoogleSignin.currentUser();
            console.log('USER', user);
            this.setState({user: user});
        }).done();
    });
}

_signIn() {
    GoogleSignin.signIn()
        .then((user) => {
            console.log('this1' + JSON.stringify(user));                
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
        })
        .done();
}

_signOut(){
    GoogleSignin.signOut()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('out');
        })
        .catch((err) => {

        });
}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                To get started, edit index.android.js
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
                Shake or press menu button for dev menu
            </Text>
            <GoogleSigninButton
                style={{width: 48, height: 48}}
                size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Icon}
                color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
                onPress={this._signIn.bind(this)}/>
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <Text onPress={this._signOut.bind(this)}>
                    signout
                </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```

:example   -->   webClientId: '1059..........googleusercontent.com' Their are two client Id  in google-services.json  oauth_client[] use first one. You can compare it with credential link given below https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials here... Name:Web client Type:web application client Id:1059........googleusercontent.com

This solve my problem.
Have a great day.
Thank You.:)

Answer (score 0):

Even I was faxing this issue, I resolved it by following below steps.

1. Create the key store and use SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.
2. Create the OAuth client Id at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials 
   [image]
3. Select Application type android, enter package name, enter SHA-1 certificate fingerprint created at step 1.

Repeat above steps for both debug and prod SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

**Note**: We need to create one more OAuth client Id by following above steps for SHA-1 generated after **APP SIGNATURE**
[image]

**Note**: We are not yet done, create one more web-application OAith Client id and **use web application client id in you react app**.
[image] 
Hope this helps some one like me!!!